# Absolute table with relative height and image inside

Tags: html, html-table

I have the following code

```css
table.charinfo {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin: 10px;
  background-color: red;
  height: 10%;
  width: 40%;
}
table.charinfo tbody {
  height: 100%;
}
table.charinfo tbody td {
  height: 100%;
  vertical-align: top;
}
table.charinfo tbody td.charimage img {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<table class="charinfo">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="charimage">
        <img src='avatar.png' />
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

It woks only in Firefox: the table has 10% of screen height and the image in the table adapts it's size.

My solution seems to be bad and works only in Firefox. How can I archive this in a correct way? (Absolute table with 10% screen height and image which adapts this height)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to calculate the 10% height in pixels

**Example using Jquery**

```
var height = $(window).height();
var tdheight = height / 10;
$(".charimage").css("height", tdheight+"px");
```

**Contain your image in the td**

```
 img {
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    margin: auto;
    display:block;
    top: 0; left: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

you can use float (left, right) or margin to position the image if you dont want it centered

**Demo**

https://jsfiddle.net/qy0gz2s6/

Comment: So it  is impossible with pure css?

Comment: @wutzebaer i'm not 100% sure as i only use chrome. if you are saying it only works in FF then i presume the height:10%; for the td is the issue. You could set the image to a specified width and height -- https://jsfiddle.net/wfzfrs6b/ -- but its not acurate